# Create an instance of @EnableJpaRepositories repository for parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**What should I pass as parameter to invoke `Access.logLastName(?)`? It's not clear to me how to put an instance of the implementation of UserRepository**

com.company.app.persistence.test.Access

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "com.company.app.persistence.repository" })
public class Access {
    static void logLastName( UserRepository repository ) {
        for (User white: repository.findByLastName( "White" )) {
            log.info( white.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

com.company.app.persistence.repository.UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

**Reference:**

Inside the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class of [Getting Started Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), they have a method like

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repository) {
  return ( args ) -> {
    repository.findByLastName( "White" );
  };
}
```

it's not clear to me how the instance of UserRepository implementation is pass as the parameter.

Comment: In your reference example, the UserRepository is injected by Spring, because the method is annotated with `@Bean`. You have to make sure, that your class is a Spring Bean and you inject the UserRepository instance (not necessarily in the method itself, but e.g. in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @dunni's comment:

> Make sure com.company.app.persistence.test.Access.java is a spring
>   bean

*It has @Configuration, which makes it qualify as a spring bean I think(?)*

then in the class where I want to invoke `logLastName()`, you can simply `@Autowired` the interface:

```
class Invoker {
  @Autowired UserRepository userRepo;

  void invoke() {
    Access.logLastName( userRepo );
  }

}
```